# How use Magick.NET LosslessCompress with Stream and IFormFile

Tags: c#, imagemagick, iformfile

I am trying to compress image(usually around 5-30) quality / size with [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET) library, and I cant really understand how can I use **ImageOptimizer** class and call **LosslessCompress**() method using stream.

- Do I need to use FileStream or MemoryStream?
- Do I need to save / create a temp file on server for each image and then proceed with the compression flow? (Performance?)
- Anything else?

*Simple Code example:*

```cs
private byte[] ConvertImageToByteArray(IFormFile image)
{
    byte[] result = null;

    // filestream
    using (var fileStream = image.OpenReadStream())

    // memory stream
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var before = fileStream.Length;

        ImageOptimizer optimizer = new ImageOptimizer();
        optimizer.LosslessCompress(fileStream); // what & how can I pass here stream?

        var after = fileStream.Length;

        // convert to byte[]
        fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        result = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot use the `fileStream` because the stream needs to be both readable and writable. If you first copy the data to a memorystream you can then compresses the image in that stream. Your code should be changed to this:

```
private byte[] ConvertImageToByteArray(IFormFile image)
{
    byte[] result = null;

    // filestream
    using (var fileStream = image.OpenReadStream())

    // memory stream
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0; // The position needs to be reset.

        var before = memoryStream.Length;

        ImageOptimizer optimizer = new ImageOptimizer();
        optimizer.LosslessCompress(memoryStream);

        var after = memoryStream.Length;

        // convert to byte[]
        result = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    return result;
}
```